# Rivals for Catan card game clarification

Tags: rivals-for-catan

Some cards (Abbey for example) have a `(1x)` next to the name.  What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?RfC-CG-Rules-092710.pdf) on page 7 has this note:

> **Please note:** Some cards are marked "1x."  This means that you may only have one of these cards in your principality.